# Calling web services in background thread and update UI on main thread

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.ios, threadpool

I have a simple login screen which authenticates user and gets their data using Restful web services. Web services works fine i call them get data, parse and store in local database. The problem is - i want to add an activity indicator on the screen while i do all this. I can add the activity indicator but the problem, it never appears on the view as control goes to call the web service and get the data.

How do i add the activity indicator while doing things in background??

I also tried to InvokeOnMainThread

```cs
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{ 

            StartActivityIndicator();
            authenticateBtn.Enabled = false;
            authenticateBtn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

        });
        // VALIDATE 
        bool isValid = ValidateTextbox ();

        if (isValid == true) {
            CreateUserAccount ();
        }
```

CreateUserAccount() method calls the web service and parse the data. If i comment line CreateUserAccount()  code works fine, i can see the activity indicator. 
But as i add the CreateUserAccount() method activity indicator never appears.

How to call a web service and perform UI activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by separating your web service calls in a Task. This will execute the service call on a separate thread and when its finished you can call InvokeOnMainThread() to do activity with the UI.

Something like this will work, place in your UIViewController.

```cs
Task CallWebService()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
         // make your service call. 
    });
}
```

Now, you could call this in your ViewDidLoad like this:

```
// Inside ViewDidLoad method of your UIViewController
//
// Show your activity indicator first.
StartActivityIndicator();
CallWebService().ContinueWith(task => {

    if(task.isFaulted)
        throw new AggregateException(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);

    // Runs when the task is finished
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        // Hide your activity indicator here. 
        StopActivityIndicator();
    });

});
```

Comment: I have a situation where as soon as i enter the app i have to call a web service to post unsaved data back to server while i keep on accessing the app. I dont know where to call InvokeOnMainThread as user could be on any view. How do we handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Live with your time, use `C#5` `async/await`:

```cs
public async void DoSomething ()
{
    StartActivityIndicator();
    authenticateBtn.Enabled = false;
    authenticateBtn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
    bool isValid = ValidateTextbox ();

    if (isValid)
        await CreateUserAccount ();

    StopActivityIndicator (); 
}
```

Comment: Also valid, but not everyone uses Async with the Xamarin stuff yet.

Comment: @therealjohn there's no valid reason not to :)

Answer (score 0):

You could place your call to CreateUserAccount in a background worker

```
 var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.DoWork += (s, ev) => ConnectToPanel();
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```